# Create React App http-proxy-middleware not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, http-proxy-middleware

So I've set up my proxies on my `create-react-app` application using `http-proxy-middleware`. I'm sure I've followed the instructions to the letter, but I keep getting a 404 every time I try to click the relevant link.

I'm using `create-react-app` v3.2.

Here's my `setupProxy.js` file:

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy("/api", { target: "http://localhost:3090" }));
};
```

Here's the action creator that makes the `http` request

```
export const signIn = formProps => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post("/api/login", formProps);

        //.....etc, etc
    } catch(e) {

        //.....etc,etc
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant route on my express server:

```
app.post("/login", requireSignIn, Authentication.login);
```

When the development server starts up, I get the following message:

```
[HPM] Proxy created: /api  -> http://localhost:3090
```

So `setupProxy.js` is obviously being picked up by CRA, but there's something wrong somewhere. I've tried adding wildcards to the proxy setup (e.g. "/api/*") but no luck. I get the following 404 logged in my console on the client side:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/api/login 404 (Not Found)
```

which refers to `localhost:3000`, suggesting that the proxy (which should redirect to `localhost:3090`) is not being used.

I can't help thinking that there's something really simple that I'm missing here, but currently tearing my hair out trying to get this to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer to this one - and as expected it was a simple error.

The routes on my express server were as follows:

```
app.post("/login", requireSignIn, Authentication.login);
```

Whereas they **should** have been:

```
app.post("api/login", requireSignIn, Authentication.login);
```

Problem solved!

Answer (score 39):

As of [`v1.0.0`](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware/releases/tag/v1.0.0) of `http-proxy-middleware`, the `setupProxy.js` file requires an explicit import; so instead of the previous default import

```
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
```

You need to use:

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware("/api", { target: "http://localhost:3090" }));
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Replace codes of setupProxy.js file as follows:

```js
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api/login',
    createProxyMiddleware({
      target: 'http://localhost:3090',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```