# Localhost refuses to connect when I make setupProxy.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, proxy

I made my setupProxy.js to deal with a CORS issue:

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use(
        proxy('/myUrl', {
            target: 'http://localhost:8090',
            changeOrigin: true
        })
    )
};
```

After I made it and run 'npm start' again, my browser says that localhost refuses to connect. If I delete setupProxy.js, I can connect to localhost, but the CORS policy blocks to connect with backend server.

Do you have any idea to connect to frontend, still using the setupProxy.js?

Comment: do you want to use the front end & backend on the same port?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this: [createProxyMiddleware](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually)

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    createProxyMiddleware('/myUrl', {
      target: 'http://localhost:8090',
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60354374/11652543

Comment: This worked for me. New version must have changed how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

See that you have spelled the name of setupProxy.js well that solved the problem for me. If that does not work. Copy and pase the fb's code the way it is into the setupProxy.js [Code can be found here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

For me the problem was that I added `"type": "module"` in my `package.json` which seems to be unsupported.